# Why is Gremlin Server / JanusGraph ignoring some of my requests?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

I'm using the Gremlin Python library to perform traversals on a JanusGraph deployment of Gremlin Server (the same also happens using just Tinkergraph). Some long traversals (with thousands of instructions) don't get a response, no errors, no timeouts, no log entries or errors on the server or client. Nothing.

The conditions for this silence treatment aren't clear. The described behaviour doesn't linearly depend on bytes or number of instructions. For instance, this code will hang forever for me:

```
g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://localhost:8182/gremlin', 't'))
g = g.inject("")
for i in range(0, 8000):
    g = g.constant("test")
print(f"submitting traversal with length={len(g.bytecode.step_instructions)}")
result = g.next()
print(f"done, got: {result}") # this is never reached
```

It doesn't depend on just the number of bytes in the request message since the number of instructions beyond which I don't get response doesn't change even with very large constant values in place of just "test". For instance, injecting 7000 values with many paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum works as expected and returns in a few milliseconds.

While it shouldn't matter (since I should be getting a proper error instead of nothing), I've already increased server-side `maxHeaderSize`, `maxChunkSize`, `maxContentLength` etc. to ridiculously high numbers. Changing the serialization format (e.g. from `GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0` to `GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1`) doesn't help either.

Note: I know that very long traversals are [an anti-pattern in Gremlin](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#long-traversals), but sometimes it's not possible or very inefficient to structure traversals such that they can use injected values instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered this question on [gremlin-users](https://groups.google.com/g/gremlin-users/c/kLyv2XLUzuE/m/vT-ZwUlcCwAJ) not realizing it was also asked here on StackOverflow. For completeness, I'll duplicate my response here.

The issue is less related to bytes and string lengths and more with the length of the traversal chain (i.e. the number of steps in your traversal). You end up hitting a JVM limit on the stack size on the server. You can increase the stack size on the jvm by changing the size of the `-Xss` value which should allow you a longer traversal length. That will likely come with the need to re-examine other JVM settings like `-Xmx` and perhaps garbage collection options.

I do find it interesting that you don't get any error messages though - you should see a stackoverflow somewhere, unless the server is just wholly bogged down by your request. I'd consider throwing more `-Xmx` at it to see if you can get it to respond with an error at least or to keep an eye on server logs to at least see it surface there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've already checked heap size and usage but forgot to mention it in my post. I'm running this with 16GB heap on a 32GB Kubernetes node with plenty of processing power. I'm not seeing any usage spikes at all, there's plenty of spare everything. I'll try increasing stack size.

Comment: Increasing stack size helped - great. I'll tentatively mark this as the answer since while it fixes the issue (thanks!) we haven't figured out how to detect this in production. How do I know it's a stack issue and not just a timeout if the server doesn't respond?  

How can I keep stack pressure low with long traversals? Looking at the source, it seems that batching parts of the traversal in sideEffect's might help, but I don't know enough about Janus/Gremlin server's inner workings. Or maybe it's the request parsing that's piling on the stack..

Comment: i suppose if the traversal is long enough it might timeout before you get a stack issue. but in one case you would get a timeout error and the other a stackoverflow exception. either should show in the server logs i would think. if you choose to use long traversals you will have to deal with stack size as it is a JVM level issue. you would have the same problem if you were writing Java and just kept endlessly chaining method calls together...sooner or later you blow the stack.

Comment: i've not experimented with `sideEffect()` step to know if that helps, but it actually sounds like it might. if your use case allows for that then perhaps that is a path to follow. personally, i'd prefer to restructure to avoid the long traversal and perhaps even take some performance hits to avoid creeping too close to stack limits.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Without long traversals, how would you perform bulk operations that touch lots of data within the same transaction?  

In theory I'm fine with trading some performance for system stability. When inserting many edges though I get 5x+ speed ups using `addE(..).from(V(from_id)).to(V(to_id))` rather than `addE(..).from(select("vertices").select(from_id)).to(select("vertices").select(to_id))` (where `vertices` is populated with required vertices beforehand). 

How might I restructure this without sacrificing so much performance?

Comment: if you must have a long run single transaction that touches that many things then i guess i'd consider using a session and submitting multiple requests on it. sessions+transactions get better support going forward into 3.5.0 so I guess I'd use scripts in 3.4.x for this specific use case until the 3.5.x line gets wide support - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2537

Comment: Is there any indication when 3.5 will land? I couldn't find any suggested dates in the issue tracker or on Github.

Comment: in approximately 2 weeks if all goes to plan. you need to follow the dev mailing list if you'd like to keep up with the release discussions: https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@tinkerpop.apache.org